# UnicodeDecodeError with QFileDialog in PyQt

Tags: python, file, pyqt, filedialog

Hello I am having an issue with my program when it comes to a file dialog function I have.

First here is my code:

```
def getFileInfo(self):
    global logName
    logName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
    return logName

def getFileName(self):
    return logName

def compareAction(self):
    def process(infile, outfile, keywords):
        keys = [[k[0], k[1], 0] for k in keywords]
        endk = None
        with open(infile, 'rb') as fdin:
            with open(outfile, 'ab') as fdout:
                fdout.write("<" + words + ">" + "\r\n")
                for line in fdin:
                    if endk is not None:
                        fdout.write(line)
                        if line.find(endk) >= 0:
                            fdout.write("\r\n")
                            endk = None
                    else:
                        for k in keys:
                            index = line.find(k[0])
                            if index >= 0:
                                fdout.write(line[index + len(k[0]):].lstrip())
                                endk = k[1]
                                k[2] += 1
        if endk is not None:
            raise Exception(endk + "Not found before end of file")
        return keys
    clearOutput = open('test.txt', 'wb')
    clearOutput.truncate()
    clearOutput.close()
    outputText = 'test.txt'
    end_token = "[+][+]"
    inputFile = logName

    start_token = self.serialInputText.toPlainText()
    split_start = start_token.split(' ')
    for words in split_start:
        process(inputFile,outputText,((words + "SHOWALL"),))
        fo = open(outputText, "rb")
        text = fo.read()

    print start_token + '\r\n'
    print split_start
    print inputFile
```

Okay, So the general idea of this piece of code is grabbing a some inputted text from a TextEdit in my PyQt GUI. Then, splitting that string into a List that can be used to '*scan*' through the file and if there are any matches then print out those matches into another text document.

**Steps:**

1. User inputs texts into TextEdit
2. Texts inside TextEdit gets stored into a QString
3. That QString has a space as a delimiter so we split each entry into a list. i.e `This is a list` -> `[u'This', u'Is', u'A', u'List']` *(The list has a u due to my code using `sip`)*
4. Now that we have this QStringList we can pass it through my `def process` function.
5. We need a file to search through obviously, this is where the `def getFileInfo(self)` and `def GetFileName(Self)` function come into play.
6. So after the user has inputted some text, selected a file to search through, he/she will press a Button, lets call it CompareButton, and it will execute the `def compareAction(self)` function.

**Issue**

Currently, my issue is this error that appears after doing all the steps it fails on step number 6. This is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RETRACTED.py", line 278, in compareAction
    process(inputFile,outputText,((words + "SHOWALL"),))
  File "RETRACTED.py", line 260, in process
    index = line.find(k[0])
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am unsure as to why this error is happening. I have been searching for a similar issue but i believe it has to do with my `process` function. I am unsure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That specific error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

looks like a problem with an (unexpected) [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM) in the input file. I suspect the log file is UTF-8 with BOM.

Try changing your file open line to:

```
open(infile, 'rb', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

to have the the BOM marker stripped from the file.